# Getting/setting properties for Kendo treeview nodes other than Id and Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have got a Kendo treeview:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)ViewBag.MyTree)
    .Events(e => e.Select("treeSelect"))
)
```

Which is filled by:

```
ViewBag.MyTree = GetInstPlacesTree();

private IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> GetInstPlacesTree()
{
    ...
   children.Add(new TreeViewItemModel
   {
       Id = child.ip.id,
       Text = child.ip.mediumDescription
   });
   ...
}
```

I want to pass, besides Id and Text, some property that can be accessed in the View, using javascript. I am able to get the Id and Text using the following function:

```
function treeSelect(e) {
    var id = $(e.node).data("id");
    var text = this.text(e.node);
}
```

But not anything else.

The TreeViewItemModel has the following properties:

```
Checked, Enabled, Encoded, Expanded,
HasChildren, HtmlAttributes, Id,
ImageHtmlAttributes, ImageUrl, Items,
LinkHtmlAttributes, Selected, SpriteCssClass,
Text, Url
```

But I can't access any of these in javascript (or I don't know how)

**EDIT**

The following suggestion produces the error shown in the image below:

```
children.Add(
  new TreeViewItemModel { Id = child.ip.id, 
                          Text = child.ip.mediumDescription, 
                         }.HtmlAttributes(new { data_value1 = "hey" })
            )
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

If it is a properties from your Model or ViewBag you can pass data using `HtmlAttributes` on your TreeView:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)ViewBag.MyTree)
    .Events(e => e.Select("treeSelect")
    ).HtmlAttributes(new { data_value1 = ViewBag.Value1 })
)
```

This renders the following data atribute on the as Treeview `data-value1="222"`.

You can then read the values in your javascript using the jQuery data method:

```
var value1 = $('#treeview').data('value1');
```

This also extends to row level entries as `TreeViewItemModel` also has the `HtmlAttributes` property. So retreiving them at row level would be as follows:

```
function treeSelect(e) {
    var id = $(e.node).data("id");
    var value1 = $(e.node).data('value1');
    var text = this.text(e.node);
}
```

**Update**

For row specific the population would be as follows:

The syntax for this means that the custom data needs to be set afterwards i.e. `HtmlAttributes.Add("data-custom", "hey");`.

Here is a simplified example that will run directly in a View (pls note this is just for demo purposes and not best practice).

```
@{
    var data = new List<TreeViewItemModel>() { 
                          new TreeViewItemModel { Id = "1", 
                          Text = "Number 1" 
                         }
};
data.First().HtmlAttributes.Add("data-custom", "hey");
}

@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .BindTo(data)
    .Events(e => e.Select("treeSelect")
    )
)

<script> 
    function treeSelect(e) {
        var id = $(e.node).data("id");
        debugger;
        var custom = $(e.node).data('custom');
        var text = this.text(e.node);
    }
</script>
```

The above simple sets the data on the first item, you may want to iterate and set values in the pre-existing collection too.

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Wouldn't that make the `data_value` the same for every node? I was looking for something like `children.Add(new TreeViewItemModel
   {
       Id = child.ip.id,
       Text = child.ip.mediumDescription, Custom = "hey"
   });`

Comment: No, you would do this: `children.Add(new TreeViewItemModel { Id = child.ip.id, Text = child.ip.mediumDescription, Custom = "hey" }.HtmlAttributes(new { Custom = "hey" })`. Custom could be set to anything. I will add to the update.  :)

Comment: The javascript variable turns to be undefined. There isn't any HTML attribute named "custom", I could that by passing a custom string into an existing HTML attribute, such as "animation: whatever" and catch the "whatever" string on the other side. This is a workaround but I was looking for something that didn't look like one

Comment: @chiapa Sorry, if you add this with the `data_` prepended:     `children.Add(
      new TreeViewItemModel { Id = child.ip.id, 
                              Text = child.ip.mediumDescription, 
                             }.HtmlAttributes(new { data_custom = "hey" })
                )` it is available in your js method as `var value1 = $(e.node).data('custom');`

Comment: @chiapa is the value to be the same for each row, or use existing data in the rows? Just it needs to be done afterwards and that will depend on my answer update.

Comment: Each tree node should have its specific value depending on some condition that I am already checking before, I just need to find a way to pass those values. As I mentioned, I'm using HTML attribute "animation" and setting it as "something", which doesn't affect the style or animation, but serves as a value carrier which I can find in the javascript via `if(e.node.style.animation == 'something')`

Comment: @chiapa I got there in the end, please see my update. In this case you should be able to loop your existing collection and do an Add depending on your specific conditions. Good luck with the rest. :)

Comment: I can't go past the first line of code in your update :) it doesn't compile, the error is shown in the bottom of my question. As I said, I am achieving it by passing it in a css property

Comment: @chiapa No worries, it works for me as you can see in the screen shot. Not sure what is happening. :)